# How can I route DNS requests to an external DNS server?

Tags: networking, dns, port-forwarding, pfsense

I have a pfsense router, and pi-hole running on an Ubuntu VM

router is `10.12.1.1.` pihole is `10.12.1.184`

I'm trying to make it so pfsense will take all dns requests and forward them to pihole.

I set up a port forward rule on pfsense to take all dns requests from any LAN IP address and forward them to `10.12.1.184`.

[image]

It doesn't work. When I enable it, no device can resolve any DNS.

Comment: In such a configuration, does the pihole receive any packets? (Check its firewall.) Kudos for actually stating *what happens* instead of merely "it doesn't work".

Comment: I'm not 100% sure it's receiving any packets. My guess is no, because when I look at the live-feed log while I have the DNS forwarding rule enabled, it shows no activity. When I disable it, the log shows every DNS query that's happening.

Comment: If you are looking at the DNS log generated by the pfsense, then obviously it wouldn't show any queries; those packets are being forwarded. I meant the system you are forwarding those **to**: does *that* show any *incoming* DNS (TCP or UDP, destination port 53) packets that correlate with DNS queries? In other words, is the port forwarding actually forwarding the packets to where you expect?

Comment: Thats what I meant. I'm looking at the log for pi hole not pfsense. When I set my devices to use pihole as the DNS server, it works. When I set pfsense to forward dns queries to pihole, and set my devices to use pfsense as their dns server, dnslook fails. So no the packets aren't being forwarded to pihole.

Comment: *"When I set pfsense to forward dns queries to pihole, and set my devices to use pfsense as their dns server, dnslook fails."* Fair enough. *"So no the packets aren't being forwarded to pihole."* I don't think you can conclude that from what you have stated.

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/51ae7c2c9fa18f6534f72a57cdd7aa86.png ----- Theres my port forward setup.